# Why won't my program run what is in the loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

My issue here is that I want it to print all four cities listed, but instead it will only print Toronto.

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] allowed = new String[] {"New York", "Singapore", "Paris", "Toronto"};

    int index;
    for(index=0; index < allowed.length - 1; index++);
    {
      System.out.println(allowed[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

If I run it without the "- 1" after the allowed.length, I get an out of bounds error. I tried converting it to a while loop as well, and still no luck. What am I missing regarding my loop?

Comment: YOU ended the loop at the semi colon following the for loop. Just remove it as suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semicolon terminates your loop body; and then you have an anonymous block. Remove the semicolon. And your test should be something like,

```
for (int index=0; index < allowed.length; index++) // ;
```

Unless you need `index` again later. Additionally, you can also print an array without a loop using [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) and something like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allowed));
```

Comment: Oh God, how did I miss that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Others have answered what you did wrong. You also asked what you're missing, so let me add something there too.

You intended for `index` to be a variable that should be used inside your loop and nowhere else. The right way to make sure it was in scope in the loop and not elsewhere was this:

```
for(int index=0; index < allowed.length - 1; index++) {
  //...
}
```

and then drop the declaration of `index` in the line above. If you had done this, then you would have discovered the semicolon typo: the compiler would have told you that `index` was not in scope in the `println()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `;`

```
for(index=0; index < allowed.length - 1; index++)
                                                 ^
                                                 |
                                                 removed `;`
{
  System.out.println(allowed[index]);
}
```

Otherwise, your loop would have an empty body.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi colon

```
for (index = 0; index < allowed.length - 1; index++);
                                                    ^
```

which is terminating the for loop. The following code block is a standalone block which is executed only once